# How to add Terms into Terms Query (ElasticSearch NEST C#)?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, ienumerable, nest

I'm writing a `TermsQuery` in NEST. I have created a `QueryContainer` for it. Here is my code:

```
QueryContainer qc1 = new TermsQuery()
{
    Field = "recordID",
    Terms = 
};
```

I want to add `int` array as Terms and it shows that terms only accept `IEnumerable<object>`. I have tried converting array to Enumbrable and it's not working.

I just want to know what kind of object Terms accept?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms accepts an `IEnumerable<object>` so it can accept a collection of any objects :) The type to use will depend on the field that you are querying against.

Given the model

```
public class Document
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

To pass it a collection of `int` or any other type

```
var termQuery = new TermsQuery
{
    Field = Infer.Field<Document>(d => d.Property1),
    Terms = new object[] { 1, 3, 5 }
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the Help! :)